# when does an AMQP/RabbitMQ channel with no connections die?

Tags: java, message-queue, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I have a simple RabbitMQ test program randomly enqueuing messages, and another reading them, all using Spring-AMQP. If the consumer dies (for example killing a process without having a chance to close its connection or channel), any messages that it had not acknowledged appear to remain unacknowledged forever.

I have seen a number of references (for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063224)) that say that the channel dies when it has no connections, and that remaining unack'd messages will be redelivered. That's not the behaviour I see - instead I get a growing list of channels marked IDLE and a growing list of connections marked running but with no activity.

Is there some configuration required to notice that connections are dead once the process has been killed?

**EDIT:**
I was running the rabbitmq server inside a VirtualBox VM, which apparently doesn't manage dead inbound connections correctly over NAT. This works just fine with the mq server running directly on the physical host.

Comment: FYI: I was having a similar problem where exclusive queues were not being cleaned up on the broker in a timely manner after the exclusive consumer dies. This prevented these components with deterministic names from starting. It was solved by setting `ConnectionFactory.RequestedHeartbeat` to a small value (seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to close. This turns out not to be a real issue.

I was running the rabbitmq server inside a VirtualBox VM, which apparently doesn't manage dead inbound connections correctly over NAT. This works just fine with the mq server running directly on the physical host.

Answer (score 4):

AMQP uses Queues and Exchanges. You publish on an exchange and you bind queues to get messages from exchanges (you can see a [short explanation](http://arnon.me/2011/08/amqp/) on my blog. When you create a queue you can set it to auto-delete as well as how much time will it stay unused before it auto deletes.
Here's a quote from the RabbitMQ quickref:

> queue.declare(short reserved-1, queue-name queue, bit passive, bit
>   durable, bit exclusive, **bit auto-delete**, no-wait no-wait, table
>   arguments) ➔ declare-ok
>
> Support: full Declare queue, create if needed.
>
> This method creates or checks a queue. When creating a new queue the
>   client can specify various properties that control the durability of
>   the queue and its contents, and the level of sharing for the queue.
>
> RabbitMQ implements extensions to the AMQP specification that permits
>   the creator of a queue to control various aspects of its behaviour.
>
> Per-Queue Message TTL This extension determines for how long a message
>   published to a queue can live before it is discarded by the server.
>   The time-to-live is configured with the x-message-ttl argument to the
>   arguments parameter of this method.
>
> **Queue Expiry** Queues can be declared with an optional lease time. The
>   lease time determines how long a queue can remain unused before it is
>   automatically deleted by the server. The lease time is provided as an
>   x-expires argument in the arguments parameter to this method.
>
> Mirrored Queues We have developed active/active high availability for
>   queues. This works by allowing queues to be mirrored on other nodes
>   within a RabbitMQ cluster. The result is that should one node of a
>   cluster fail, the queue can automatically switch to one of the mirrors
>   and continue to operate, with no unavailability of service. To create
>   a mirrored queue, you provide an x-ha-policy argument in the arguments
>   parameter to this method.

Comment: I don't want the queue to be deleted, I want it to be persistent. But I also want the unacknowledged messages (consumed by processes that died before acknowledging) to be redelivered. It's the dead connections/channels that need deleting, not messages.

Comment: ok now I got you - you need to create ConnectionParameters instance and set a heartbeat (setRequestedHeardbeat) to a reasonable value (1 heartbeat miss will close the channel) Then pass that to the ConnectionFactory constructor

Comment: @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz, setting `RequestedHeartbeat` solved my similar problem which was manifesting by exclusive queues not being cleaned up on the broker in a timely manner. This prevented components which declare exclusive queues with deterministic names from starting.

Comment: @drstevens right- that's pretty much the same issue. The broker needs to know that clients are gone to release resources