# I am using rabbitmq in Spring framework, how to call basicRecover on connection create?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq spring framework. There is an issue with my queues, during my rabbitmq consumer deployment, the suddenly disconnect will left unacked messages behind.

```
<rabbit:listener-container id="MyListenerContainer"
    connection-factory="MyRabbitConsumerConnectionFactory"
    prefetch="100"
    concurrency="5"
    acknowledge="manual"
    auto-startup="true">
    <rabbit:listener queues="MyRabbitQueue" ref="MyConsumer"/>
```

```
<rabbit:queue id="MyRabbitQueue"
              name="MyRabbitQueue"
              declared-by="MyConsumerRabbitAdmin"
              auto-delete="false"
              durable="true"
              exclusive="false"/>

<rabbit:admin id="MyConsumerRabbitAdmin"
              connection-factory="MyRabbitConsumerConnectionFactory"
              auto-startup="true"/>
```

MyConsumer implemented ChannelAwareMessageListener interface. 
How can I issue basicRecover(true) method during connection create?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory`:

```
/**
 * Enables or disables <a href="http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery">automatic connection recovery</a>.
 * @param automaticRecovery if true, enables connection recovery
 * @see <a href="http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery">Automatic Recovery</a>
 */
public void setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(boolean automaticRecovery) {
    this.automaticRecovery = automaticRecovery;
}
```

it is `false` by default.

Comment: I have enabled automaticRecovery. I can got connection recovered. My issue after I stop my consumer (stop the process of my consumer), and then restart it later. There are many unacked message left behind at the moment of the stop consumer. So I want to call basicRecover when the first time connection got established.

Comment: I don't want speculate and copy/paste, so I'm sending you to the proper link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063224

Comment: I added a channelListener on ConnectionFactory. in onCreate method, I will issue channel.basicRecover(true). I have one concern, the redelivered messages have redelivery flag set as true due to channel.basicRecover(true)?

Comment: From my perspective it's correct. Your messages has been delivered once already. So, that good that recovery track it and let your new consumer know that there was something unexpected before.

Comment: is the redelivered flag set as true in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but your experiments confirm that (see your comment above). Isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RabbitMQ Management HTTP API to list all the channels, then on the details of each channel you can see how long it has been idle and react accordingly, closing the channel for example, which would automatically nack any un-acked messages still hanging around on that channel.

See here: http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html